# ./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I followed [Hyperledger composer tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) and failed to execute the fifth command of **2nd step** `./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a`
Here is the fail result:

```
...    
CORE_PEER_ID=cli
    CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
    CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
    2018-07-03 09:43:09.912 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
    2018-07-03 09:43:09.912 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
    2018-07-03 09:43:09.936 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 003 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.18.0.9:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 <nil>}
    2018-07-03 09:43:10.937 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 004 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.18.0.9:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 <nil>}
    2018-07-03 09:43:12.642 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 005 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.18.0.9:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 <nil>}
    Error: Error getting endorser client channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

I check images status from **peer0** in docker using `docker ps -a | grep peer0` whose result

```
d7929f0332f4        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                              "peer node start"        About an hour ago   Up About an hour          0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
ac09650d3e5b        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                              "peer node start"        About an hour ago   Up About an hour          0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
4faf09d23b48        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.3-ccfa7421a9e100115b8beac460d72ce0ce0e48cd38b00ab9b1ea6b7de230bc0a   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   4 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                                                       dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.3
bc0fc72c1c45        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.2-406300108c533f71ddcfc602aa3bb51c3bd82126f6cb16cfca1ed2328bc080a1   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   25 hours ago        Exited (0) 7 hours ago                                                       dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.2
62585d29cfa6        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1-6695b9314667cc296171c0da511644e9011aa9a3ba0f6e759aca9e32e458803c   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   2 days ago          Exited (0) 25 hours ago                                                      dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1
```

I check logs of each images except those belongs to previous network version `0.0.1` & `0.0.2`.
From  `4faf09d23b48` image using command `docker logs 4faf09d23b48 | tail -1`, it shows error result unlike others.

```
2018-07-03T07:06:15.973Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AssetRegistry' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.061Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.141Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.TransactionRegistry' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.212Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.278Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.345Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddAsset' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.439Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateAsset' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.509Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.RemoveAsset' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.580Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.639Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateParticipant' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.727Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.RemoveParticipant' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.796Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.873Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.IssueIdentity' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:16.940Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.BindIdentity' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:17.009Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ActivateCurrentIdentity' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:17.086Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.RevokeIdentity' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:17.158Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.StartBusinessNetwork' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:17.232Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ResetBusinessNetwork' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:17.297Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.SetLogLevel' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:17.367Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.example.mynetwork.Commodity' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:17.493Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Participant:org.example.mynetwork.Trader' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:17.591Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.example.mynetwork.Trade' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:17.695Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.example.mynetwork.RemoveHighQuantityCommodities' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:17.848Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:17.851Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :Resolver                 :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","    at <anonymous>","    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]}
2018-07-03T07:06:18.050Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'admin' in collection with ID 'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:18.051Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :Resolver                 :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID 'admin' in collection with ID 'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not exist Error: Object with ID 'admin' in collection with ID 'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","    at <anonymous>","    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]}
2018-07-03T07:06:18.338Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:06:18.338Z [18edf5bc] ERROR    :Resolver                 :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","    at <anonymous>","    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]}
2018-07-03T07:07:03.957Z [957698e1] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'e9b055f025400be5cb02556cead788819bef2bcee494cd8781c1b5df0d112b99' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:07:03.980Z [957698e1] ERROR    :IdentityManager          :validateIdentity()        Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '01899e04161a3a6d64670504fa122e55818295352929b6a616333a3739fde3f2', must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED)
2018-07-03T07:07:03.980Z [957698e1] ERROR    :Engine                   :invoke()                  Caught error, rethrowing {"stack":["{Error}The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '01899e04161a3a6d64670504fa122e55818295352929b6a616333a3739fde3f2', must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED) Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '01899e04161a3a6d64670504fa122e55818295352929b6a616333a3739fde3f2', must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED)","    at IdentityManager.validateIdentity (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime/lib/identitymanager.js:136:27)","    at NodeContext.loadCurrentParticipant (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime/lib/context.js:82:39)","    at <anonymous>","    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]}
2018-07-03T07:07:03.987Z [957698e1] ERROR    :Composer                 :Invoke()                  Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '01899e04161a3a6d64670504fa122e55818295352929b6a616333a3739fde3f2', must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED)
2018-07-03T07:07:03.990Z ERROR [lib/handler.js] [composerchannel-957698e1]Calling chaincode Invoke() returned error response [Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '01899e04161a3a6d64670504fa122e55818295352929b6a616333a3739fde3f2', must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED)]. Sending ERROR message back to peer 
2018-07-03T07:07:04.072Z [9e142fed] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'e9b055f025400be5cb02556cead788819bef2bcee494cd8781c1b5df0d112b99' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:07:04.085Z [9e142fed] ERROR    :IdentityManager          :validateIdentity()        Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '01899e04161a3a6d64670504fa122e55818295352929b6a616333a3739fde3f2', must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED)
2018-07-03T07:07:04.124Z [9e142fed] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'e9b055f025400be5cb02556cead788819bef2bcee494cd8781c1b5df0d112b99' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity' does not exist
2018-07-03T07:32:54.684Z ERROR [lib/handler.js] Chat stream with peer - on error: "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF\n    at createStatusError (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)\n    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:270:19)\n    at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:248:8)\n    at /usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:804:12" 
2018-07-03T07:18:54.911Z [a3cb0193] DEBUG    :Composer                 :@PERF Invoke()            Total (ms) duration for txnID [a3cb019391ff4e789db3bbbffba3bf4fa4021d805978424023683d07b13d17c1]: 87.00
```

Comment: 1) your first error is a docker networking issue. Where did you clone your fabric-samples from? This tutorial (if all the steps are followed correctly) has been working perfectly for months now. It uses Fabric v1.1 GA images. 2) the channel set up in that multi-org is `mychannel` - I notice you've got `composerchannel`  in your logs - this channel is defined in the Developer tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial - 3) did you do a teardown of your environment - before going on to do the Multi-org tutorial, as instructed in the tutorial ?

Comment: 4) Lastly you may have got some old cards from a previous tutorial lying about - suggest to clear out your old cards from $HOME/.composer .

Comment: Really appreciate your advice @PaulO'Mahony, first of all I basically clone as followed: `git clone -b issue-6978 https://github.com/sstone1/fabric-samples.git` but I doubt what I did regarding `mychannel` maybe I have to redefine. Third, I did `./stopFabric.sh
./teardownFabric.sh` accordingly to [https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org]. Last, I removed card by using ` rm -fr ~/.composer`.

Answer (score 0):

see the ANSWER specifically, on this thread -> [Error: pathspecs with curl -sSL [shortened-url-here] | bash -s 1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170675/error-pathspecs-with-curl-ssl-shortened-url-here-bash-s-1-1-0)

I think the errors are because your CouchDB container does not exist (amongst other errors above)

If you follow the tutorial (with the curl command as suggested in the ANSWER (ie extra parameters)) - you should be able to carry on successfully with the tutorial.