# Error: pathspecs with curl -sSL [shortened-url-here] | bash -s 1.1.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

According to [hyperledger-composer tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org), to deploy network with multi-organization I need to clean previous installation of composer:

```
cd ~/fabric-dev-servers
./stopFabric.sh
./teardownFabric.sh
```

After that, I cloned **hyperledger/fabric-sample branch**

```
git clone -b issue-6978 https://github.com/sstone1/fabric-samples.git
```

Then, navigate to fabric-sample and download specific binaries from the repository with shortened link

```
curl -sSL [shortened-url-here] | bash -s 1.1.0
```

Right after that, one error thrown

```
===> Checking out v1.1.0 branch of hyperledger/fabric-samples
error: pathspec 'v1.1.0' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Plus, there some more relating to several images

```
Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.2.0-rc1 not found
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.2.0-rc1
===> Pulling thirdparty docker images
==> THIRDPARTY DOCKER IMAGE: couchdb

Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.8 not found
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.8
==> THIRDPARTY DOCKER IMAGE: kafka

Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-kafka:x86_64-0.4.8 not found
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka:x86_64-0.4.8
==> THIRDPARTY DOCKER IMAGE: zookeeper

Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper:x86_64-0.4.8 not found
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper:x86_64-0.4.8
```

I also attach with the full result of above errors

```
bp1@bp1-VirtualBox:~/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples$ curl -sSL [shortened-url here] | bash -s 1.1.0

Installing hyperledger/fabric-samples repo

===> Checking out v1.1.0 branch of hyperledger/fabric-samples
error: pathspec 'v1.1.0' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Installing Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version x86_64-1.1.0 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/releases/org/hyperledger/fabric/hyperledger-fabric/linux-amd64-1.1.0/hyperledger-fabric-linux-amd64-1.1.0.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 35.4M  100 35.4M    0     0   145k      0  0:04:09  0:04:09 --:--:--  135k
==> Done.
===> Downloading version x86_64-1.2.0-rc1 platform specific fabric-ca-client binary
===> Downloading:  https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/releases/org/hyperledger/fabric-ca/hyperledger-fabric-ca/linux-amd64-1.2.0-rc1/hyperledger-fabric-ca-linux-amd64-1.2.0-rc1.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 4939k  100 4939k    0     0   153k      0  0:00:32  0:00:32 --:--:--  205k
==> Done.

Installing Hyperledger Fabric docker images

===> Pulling fabric Images
==> FABRIC IMAGE: peer

x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-peer
Digest: sha256:57417699ddf50c5ebd47a9a2cc74c0324fbba0281eb1104b9ddd05a67776b01f
Status: Image is up to date for hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: orderer

x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-orderer
Digest: sha256:0c3a3b5ecfd24b513da22bbb77da7b3f5bca9c121cc0ac5c46ba04c97c163654
Status: Image is up to date for hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: ccenv

x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-ccenv
Digest: sha256:07818367dc6d4264472d24b21819f9dc4e16e890d81ddfacee0341a22d72050b
Status: Image is up to date for hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:x86_64-1.1.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: tools

x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-tools
1be7f2b886e8: Already exists 
6fbc4a21b806: Already exists 
c71a6f8e1378: Already exists 
4be3072e5a37: Already exists 
06c6d2f59700: Already exists 
4d536120d8a5: Already exists 
0baaf9ec263e: Already exists 
3ea9b6cc6f21: Already exists 
6173b9a5fe5e: Already exists 
e73719e0bcbe: Already exists 
b55408c6ced5: Already exists 
1a8bca84adfa: Pull complete 
b54c1992cc9c: Pull complete 
68093aff3e84: Pull complete 
3827dc0ff46d: Pull complete 
1e22360bf4e7: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:36d7fa8e8ddcc19fed8e1c3c06bc6ae1dac18c35e8a884188d2c08df3e5a4472
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.1.0
===> Pulling fabric ca Image
==> FABRIC CA IMAGE

Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.2.0-rc1 not found
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.2.0-rc1
===> Pulling thirdparty docker images
==> THIRDPARTY DOCKER IMAGE: couchdb

Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.8 not found
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.8
==> THIRDPARTY DOCKER IMAGE: kafka

Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-kafka:x86_64-0.4.8 not found
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka:x86_64-0.4.8
==> THIRDPARTY DOCKER IMAGE: zookeeper

Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper:x86_64-0.4.8 not found
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper:x86_64-0.4.8

===> List out hyperledger docker images
hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                                x86_64-1.1.0        72617b4fa9b4        3 months ago        299MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                                                                                             latest              b7bfddf508bc        3 months ago        1.46GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                                                                                             x86_64-1.1.0        b7bfddf508bc        3 months ago        1.46GB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                                           latest              ce0c810df36a        3 months ago        180MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                                           x86_64-1.1.0        ce0c810df36a        3 months ago        180MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                              latest              b023f9be0771        3 months ago        187MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                              x86_64-1.1.0        b023f9be0771        3 months ago        187MB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                                                                                             latest              c8b4909d8d46        3 months ago        1.39GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                                                                                             x86_64-1.1.0        c8b4909d8d46        3 months ago        1.39GB
hyperledger/fabric-baseimage                                                                                         x86_64-0.4.6        dbe6787b5747        4 months ago        1.37GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                                           x86_64-0.4.6        7e73c828fc5b        4 months ago        1.56GB
```

Please kindly share some advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Due to recent Fabric changes, there is a change in behaviour that we should capture in the tutorial..

Please try `curl -sSL [shortened-url-here] | bash -s 1.1.0  1.1.0  0.4.6` - ie 3 parameters, separated by spaces, to the `bash -s` command above and specifically those versions.

You can ignore the `error: pathspec 'v1.1.0'` message for now, as we're using a custom repo for the tutorial.

Comment: however I wonder whether what do the other **2 parameters** refer to. Thanks again, let see if it works.

Comment: fabric version, fabric-ca version, baseimage version

Comment: damn, this got me stuck for hours. Thanks

I would highly recomend them to also update the older documentation (eg : https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/samples.html#binaries)

Answer (score 0):

**You can manually pull all those images. (Errors because of wrong version no in the script)**

- docker pull  hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.0
- docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0